# can't comb hair down

Tags: particles, hair

I have this human model and I want to put hairs on it.

I want the hair to be laying/hanging on to his forhead but for some reason the hairs are unable to do that. it looks like there is some invisible wall or something where the hair can't go through.

maybe something to do with collision or something but I cant figure it out.

rotating the individual hairs also doesnt work.

Please check out my .blend file and try to rotate or comb the hairs down because I can't (blender 2.8)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Turns out its just a simple option you have to tick off.